# Not able to fetch input data in bar graph

Tags: reactjs, charts, bar-chart

how to take input and make a bar graph using the input in react js

was able to fetch it with static data.but was not able to do it with dynamic data.

I am a bigenner and need some guidence.

Comment: did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790466/get-json-data-from-api-and-map-in-barchart-reactjs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.